# Weightage for interpolation

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, probability, interpolation, mathematical-optimization

i was learning natural language processing from [This site](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/19).

I was stuck in the interpolation video.

The professor says that: P'(W<sub>n</sub> | W<sub>n-1</sub> , W<sub>n-2</sub>) = λ<sub>1</sub> * P(W<sub>n</sub> | W<sub>n-1</sub> , W<sub>n-2</sub>) + λ<sub>2</sub> * P(W<sub>n</sub> | W<sub>n-1</sub>) + λ<sub>3</sub> * P(W<sub>n</sub>)

Then he tells that: to set the lambdas, you take a 'held out' set of data and find the lambda that maximizes the probability of that set of data.

Does that mean that you loop through all possible numbers (which is infinity) and then find which one of them maximizes the probability?

Well that's impossible right? Then how do you choose the lambdas. Finding the lambda which increases the probability is easy, also finding the probability is easy, but choosing the lambda is a big deal.

Please help me in choosing the lambdas!

Thankyou in advance!!

Comment: this could be a regression problem. given training set have values of both left and right side of the equation, you can find out the best λ optimization. noticed you are taking course form coursera, if you take a look the 'machine learning' course, you will find more details in the 'cost function' lecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your weights according to the order of word's importance but make sure that the weights add up to 1 because probabilities cannot be more than 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a semi-educated guess at best, but it looks like what he's doing is iteratively improving his function for P(Wn | Wn-1 , Wn-2), using the previous estimate of that function, as well as estimates for P(Wn | Wn-1) and P(Wn).  He is making the assumption that the new function is a weighted sum of the old functions, and those λ values are the weights.  Those weights must sum to one.

Your job is to find the best set of weights.

You solve that sort of problem, not by looping through λ values (as you correctly intuit) but with math.  Without knowing more about the structures of those functions, it's hard to say much more that is useful.

If you're lucky, you can find a relatively simple calculus expression to do this.  If you are unlucky, it will be a relatively complicated procedure involving (perhaps) the method of lagrange multipliers.  It might not even have an obvious closed form expression, leading to various hill-climbing, expectation-maximization or other techniques.  I really couldn't say.